# PHP CodeIgniter - Método construtor retorna parametros vázios

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Usando o CodeIgniter 2, tenho uma classe chamada PagamentosRealizadosPdf(). O mesmo é uma Lib.

Dentro da Model eu a chamo dessa forma:

```
$this->load->library("PagamentosRealizadosPdf", null, "pdf");
$pdf = PagamentosRealizadosPdf::GerarPdf($grouped_pagamentos, $id_contrato_name, $logo_empreendimento, "Extrato Pagamentos Realizados", $tipo_grupo, $send_email);
```

No método estático GerarPdf() eu pego os parametros e passo para o construtor:

```
public static function GerarPdf($grupo_pagamentos, $name, $logo, $title, $filtro, $save = true)
{
    $pdf = new PagamentosRealizadosPdf($grupo_pagamentos, $name, $logo, $title, $filtro);
    return $pdf->GeraPdf($save);
}
```

Quando debugo para ver se os parametros estão chegando no construtor, o mesmo não retorna nada.

```
public function __construct($pagamentos_agrupados = [], $empreendimento = "Nome do Empreendimento", $logo = "", $name = "", $filtro = "P")
{
    show($pagamentos_agrupados); die;
 
    parent::__construct("L", "mm", "A4");

    $this->logo = $logo;
    $this->pagamentos = $pagamentos_agrupados;
    $this->empreendimento = $empreendimento;
    $this->filtro = $filtro;
        
    $this->SetTitle($name);
}
```

Comment: show($pagamentos_agrupados); die; pelo código é fácil entender que não exibe nada! você deu um `die`!

Comment: @novice por que isso impacta?

Comment: Se você irá invocar a sua classe por método estático, qual é a função de chamar o `load->library`  do  CI?

Comment: @Woss... sem isso não funciona.

O CI 2 ele solicita, quando envio o mesmo da erro 500 quando retiro essa instrução.

Comment: Mas aí o erro é de classe não definida, não é? Você literalmente está instanciando a classe através do CI sem passar  parâmetros (que é o que estranhou), para não usar essa instância e criá-la de novo.

Comment: @Woss....a pessoa que fez esse código fez no seguinte pensamento.

Instanciar a classe sem chamar o metodo construtor

Por isso que nessa parte ele chama de cara o metro estático.
$pdf = PagamentosRealizadosPdf::GerarPdf($grouped_pagamentos, $id_contrato_name, $logo_empreendimento, "Extrato Pagamentos Realizados", $tipo_grupo, $send_email);

Então,... dentro do método estático(GerarPdf()) eu chamo a própria classe PagamentosRealizadosPdf().

Só que os parametros quando jogado dentro do construtor, meio que perde todos os valores.

O dev que fez isso informou que rodava normalmente.

Comment: Você está focando no problema ao invés de na solução. Não faz sentido fazer o que foi feito, independente de quem fez e porquê fez. O problema está acontecendo por carregar a biblioteca sem necessidade pelo CI. Ou faz uma coisa, ou faz outra. "Funcionava", mas a classe sempre era instanciada com parâmetros vazios na primeira vez. O que talvez mudou é que você quer ver esses valores, mas a questão é que está vendo os valores da primeira instância e não da segunda.

Comment: @Woss.... segui o seu conselho.

Fiz um debug na chamada da bibliotéca.. $this->load->library... realmente nessa chamada ela já instância o método.

Dessa forma, eu fiz o seguinte.

$this->load->library(<nome-método>, <array-com-parametros>);

Dessa forma funciona perfeitamente.